# RFID-RC522 Can't read from MIFARE Ultralight

Tags: arduino-uno, rfid

I tried many ways to get and print UID and other data from a MIFARE Ultralight, but it always ends with an error. I am using the RFID-RC522 reader with an Arduino UNO and thr [MFRC522 Library](https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid).

I can normally get and print the PICC type of the chip, but that's the only thing that works.

This is how I have connected my RC522 reader:

[image]
<sub>(source: [ytimg.com](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/23aMjljCLZI/maxresdefault.jpg))</sub>

This is my code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define RST_PIN 9
#define SS_PIN 10

MFRC522 rfid(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);

unsigned long noSignal = 0;

bool lastState = true;
bool read = true;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(2, OUTPUT); //Red led
    pinMode(3, OUTPUT); //Green led

    Serial.begin(9600);
    SPI.begin();
    while (!Serial);

    rfid.PCD_Init();
    Serial.println("RFID ctecka byla uspesne spustena."); //Prints "RFID Reader succesfully started"
    Serial.println();

    changeLed(true);
}

void changeLed(bool red) 
{
    digitalWrite(2, red);
    digitalWrite(3, !red);
}

void loop()
{
    if (millis() - noSignal >= 300) 
    {
        changeLed(true);
        read = true;
    }

    bool state = !rfid.PICC_IsNewCardPresent() && !rfid.PICC_ReadCardSerial();

    if (state != lastState)
        if (state)
            noSignal = millis();
        else if (read)
        {
            read = false;

            changeLed(false);
            noSignal = millis();

            Serial.println("---------Cip detekovan----------"); //Prints "Chip detected"
            Serial.println();

            MFRC522::PICC_Type piccType = rfid.PICC_GetType(rfid.uid.sak);

            Serial.print("Znacka cipu: ");//Prints chip type
            Serial.println(rfid.PICC_GetTypeName(piccType));

            rfid.PICC_DumpToSerial(&rfid.uid); //Here is the error

            Serial.println();
            Serial.println("---------Cteni skoncilo----------");//prints "Read ended"
            Serial.println();

            rfid.PICC_HaltA();
            rfid.PCD_StopCrypto1();
        }

    lastState = state;
}
```

Serial monitor snapshot:

[image]

Maybe an important thing is that when I call `PCD_DumpVersionToSerial()` I get:

```
Firmware Version: 0x12 = (unknown)
```

Somewere I read that my Arduino isn't compatibile with MIFARE Ultralight and I need MIFARE Classic cards. Is that true? Can I solve this problem by using another library or is it a hardware problem?

**EDIT:**
I asked my friend, who has an Arduino too from the same shop as me, if he can read MIFARE Ultralight cards. He said that it's working for him. So my problem will be probably on the hardware side. We both have unofficial Arduinos from AliExpress.

Answer (score 3):

In the first lines of code there are two lines that say:

```
#define RST_PIN 9
#define SS_PIN 10
```

They define the RESET pin to be on the D9 pin and the SDA on the D10 pin.
So you have an connection error try connecting like shown and you should be good to go.

[image: default connection]

Comment: Sorry, I made mistake. I have connected pins like in your picture. I will update my question.

Comment: @DavidMoškoř have you tried the original example?

Comment: Yes, same result

Comment: Is it possible that my cards are using encryption `DES3` that my arduino cannot decrypt?

Comment: @DavidMoškoř it is possible that your card use a different frequency.